# Application not running under .Net 4.5 on Server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm running Windows 2012 with `.Net 2.0` applications.  I have `.Net 4.5` installed and tried running an application set to that.  I have the app pool set to use .Net 4 but when I run the application I am getting errors like its not using the correct framework.  The application works fine on other servers that are running only `.Net 4` applications. Some suggestions are to re-register `.net` but will this affect my applications running 2.0?

Comment: No matter what you should post the exact error message, instead of letting every reader guess. Microsoft announced years ago some of the major breaking changes, http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes so spend your precious time on some homework.

Comment: Posting error message can help us understand how to help you.